# Jquery 'this' keyword

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-droppable

I am working on a drag and drop project, but whenever I drag an item, it only calls the `addsgr();` function. Here is my Jquery code:

```
$(".productItem").draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    handle: "productItem"
});

$("#basket").droppable({
    accept: ".productItem",
    drop: function(event, ui){
        $("<div></div>")
            .html(ui.draggable.text())
            .appendTo($(this));
            //work on id

            if(this.id=="brnsgr"){
                addbrnsgr();
            }else if(this.id="sgr"){
                addsgr();
            }else if(this.id="flour"){
                addflour();
            }else if(this.id="bkpwdr"){
                addbkpwdr();
            }else if(this.id="butter"){
                addbutter();
            }




    }
});
```

Comment: What is `droppable`? Read the documentation of that jQuery plugin for info regarding `this` in its `drop`  callback.

Comment: What does `console.log(this.id)` show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not comparing you are assigning the variable

try this

```js
if(event.target.id=="brnsgr"){
    addbrnsgr();
}else if(event.target.id=="sgr"){
    addsgr();
}else if(event.target.id=="flour"){
    addflour();
}else if(event.target.id=="bkpwdr"){
    addbkpwdr();
}else if(event.target.id=="butter"){
    addbutter();
}
```

Comment: So it's a typo?

Comment: I tried that, but now it doesn't call any function.

Comment: Don't bother posting an answer for the common `=` vs `==` typo. Just post a comment and flag it for closing.

Comment: You also changed `this` to `event.target`. Is that relevant to the solution?